# I want to do a bridge between ubuntu and my ps3

Tags: network-bridge, ps3

Hello I have been trying to put bridge mode on ubuntu basically my setup I've got a router upstairs that I usually get wireless to my laptop which is connected ethernet to my ps3, so my ps3 gets connected through my laptop

```
             ethernet
```

WIFI ---- LAPTOP ----------- PS3

Now on winxp this doesn't pose me a problem at all I just select local area connection and the wireless connection just select them and click create bridge.

Howewer in Ubuntu I couldn't do it, so I started looking around etc and setting manually then I installed bridge-utils, firestarter and netbridge still nothing

Then i used the command sudo ifconfig.

I was looking to see if I add any device with that unknown mac address for eth0 which I hadn't so I looked around more and there is an utility that changes the mac address. However as soon I change the mac address it resets itself right away. Is there a FIX to this so that it is set permanently because that is not recognized anywhere.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down

sudo macchanger -m XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX eth0

sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

These are the commands I use. Is there a way to edit them into a script and put the script somewhere to make this solution permanent? I've seen somewhere that you could edit them in sysconfig but I used ctrl+h and didn't find sysconfig and those files to edit there.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

EDIT: I forgot to say I am running Ubuntu version 11.10

Comment: Please consider adding more interpunction to your post, personally I find it quite hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your PS3 is connected to your laptop using Ethernet, do:

- Click on the network icon in the top right of your screen
- Click "Edit connections..."
- Click "Edit..." for the appropriate connection with your PS3
- Click the tab "IPv4 settings"
- Under "Method", select "Shared with other computers"
- Click "Save..."

Note that you may need a crossover UTP cable to make this work. Also, I would advise to undo any changes you have made to the system in your pursuit of making this work.

Comment: Ok Cumulus007.

Regarding the solution you posted it didn't work, I also already had tested it before because I have been changing values everywhere and everytime if it doesn't work I put them back on their normal state.

What I need to know right now, is how to change eth0 mac address permanently , so that it never comes back to this eth0 mac address that corresponds to reality.

I want to know a method better than macchanger.

That might solve the problem thanks.

Comment: @likewyise Are you sure you are using a crossover UTP cable?  Also did you actually test this just now, or are you assuming that it is one of the many "values" you have been changing? Because frankly the answer to your mac address question is simple (create a bash script, set a cron job) but I highly doubt it will help you do what you want to do in the least.

Comment: @adampewolff: Isn't an ethernet cable the same as a crossover UTP cable?

Also supossing I get a crossover UTP cable I have set the ethernet cable already, so that when I go back to windows xp, I get online in my ps3 via windows xp, doing that and getting a new cable if this cable is different from an ethernet cable, would make me have to change the cables everytime, unless this crossover utp cable you are talking about works in both systems.

And regarding the bash script and set a cron job where can I find more info regarding that? Thanks

Comment: This solution simply must work. Have you activated the new connection from the network menu? Did you undo any of the scripts you have been fiddling around with, including the mac changer?

Comment: Well I uninstalled every program I was able to get and erased everything, bought the crossover UTP cable and it still doesn't work, I also tried in both connections in wired and in wireless to put "Shared with other computers".

Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Well looks like it won't work because that in Ubuntu 11.10 the ipv6 addresses need to be set to ignore and then sudo killall dnsmasq but it still isn't working so I don't know what else to do

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 12.04? I use this feature under 12.04 on a regular basis and absolutely no problems ever occured, using various setups.

Comment: No I don't want to upgrade to 12.04 or any other versions past 11.10 I want this version 11.10 because it has a specific thing that makes it work with a program I installed that none other version has it.

I already disabled ipv6 but it encounters problems since it won't work.

I was trying a new method in which I needed to disable the network and it showed up an error: "RTNETLINK answers: no such process".

Also one thing that bothers me is that I have eth0 and eth1 and not wlan0, but my laptop is connected wirelessly to my router so what is happenning in here is it normal?

Comment: I might go and burn on a disc Ubuntu 12.04 just to check what really is the problem going around here if it is really from 11.10 or it is just an hardware problem

Comment: I just tried with Ubuntu 12.04 the same problems are still occuring so there is no way I can make this work?